# Audio Player to stop playing when new song is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, audio, handlebars.js

I am making a simple web audio player using jquery, handlebars, html5. My player works when the first link is clicked, but if another song link is clicked the original keeps playing and the only way to get it to play another song is to refresh the page. I'd like it to stop playing the initial song and start playing the new song that has been clicked. I tried to get it into a jsfiddle but couldn't get it all to work so I put it up online

[Here](http://www.koltondallas.com/222/BookSearch/)

I know it looks awful now, I am just trying to get it to work before I go further with the design. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer to my own question. Two stupid lines of code. My downfall was not telling it to load it.

```
 audioPlayerDiv.src=songInfo.source;
 audioPlayerDiv.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing the src when a new song is clicked:
Give the source tag an id.
`<source src="media/1.mp3" type="audio/wav" id="audioSource">`

```
function change(songURL) { //called when a song link is clicked.
  var player = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
  var source = document.getElementById("audioSource");

  if(source.src != songURL) {
    //set the players src to the new song
    source.src = songURL;
    player.load();
    player.play();
  }
}
```

Something like that

Comment: Thanks, Im messing around for this now. Would it not be in some sort of if statement looking to see if the player is already going? I could be way off. Im new to this stuff

Comment: That true, you should check to see if the player's src isn't the src playing.

Comment: It got me going. I think it will work if I find out how to correctly detect if the player is playing. Do you know how I would detect that?

Comment: does it matter?  If it isn't playing, a click will start it with the song.  If it is playing, it will change songs.

Comment: probably not, just confused. the way I have it currently, I had to put your function outside of my document.ready function and I am having a hard time getting the "source" because of all of this template stuff.

Comment: on line 77 of main.js is where you should add it.  You called the player id "audioPlayer", and if you give the source an id, the above should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66612/discussion-between-user2980869-and-norcalknockout).